# Какая наиболее верная структура html сайта?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, вёрстка, cms

Сколько не создавал сайтов, все они были связаны с CMS. Теперь столкнулся с задачей создание сайта без cms, только html,css и js. Однако немогу для себя решить вопрос, каким образом строится файловая структура таких сайтов.
К примеру, есть главная папка publuc_html:

- assets(служебные файлы, типа css, img, js);
- pages (отвечает за страницы сайта, blog, contacts и прочее);
- index.html
- favicon.ico
  как организовать структуру, чтобы путь к странице blog был вида site.ru/blog,
  а не как получается выше site.ru/pages/blog

Или правильнее будет создавать иерархию вида:
public_html:

- index.html
- blog.html
- contacts.html
- и т.д.

Однако думаю, что это не лучший вариант в случае, если страниц будет много,
поделитесь своим опытом, буду благодарен полезной инфе по этой теме.

Comment: для статики вообще без разницы , для примера https://pages.github.com ... там и тренируйтесь

Comment: @Максим Ленский, что значит без разницы? 1000 страниц в главной директории или 1000 папок со своими файлами в папке pages, есть ведь какая-то принятая точка зрения в данном вопросе

Comment: тысяча папок ? не порьте  мозги - гитхаб в помощь

Comment: Максим, спасибо за мнение, но гитхаб или другой хостинг у меня есть, тренироваться в никуда, просто переставляя файлы не имеет большого смысла, прошу подсказать инструкцию, как делается "обычно". Если нет мнения на этот счет, не стоит переводить тему.

Comment: нету инструкций - структура создаётся так как хочется исполнителю .. но так что бы в css был файл стилей в js были скрипты или папку js разбить на plugins и по отдельности всё подключать .. вообще этот вопрос не имеет смысла ..

Answer (score 1):

Советую взять за основу иерархию фреймворка Laravel (php), отдельно папка для подключаемых файлов (стили, js) отдельно папка для тем (шаблонов страниц), все интуитивно понятно и просто.